# C# display a point cloud

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I got the point cloud data (9830400byte array) in windows, which cames from ubuntu ROS Indigo. As far as i know the 9830400byte = 640 * 480 * 4 chanels(rgba) * 8(different z corinates). And **i wanted to display it in a windows form. Anyone know any method how can i do it?**

Thanks for your help!

Beni

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196486/c#-display-a-point-cloud/) by [benyke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20671/benyke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-02**:
How are you getting your point cloud data? Do you have a ROS subscriber on windows, or some other way of transferring the point cloud data?

**Comment by [benyke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20671/benyke/) on 2014-11-03**:
I have a ROS.NET client on windows, and i subscibed to /camera/depth/points with a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 message type. And i ment the uint8[] data size is 9830400byte = 640 * 480 * 4 chanels(rgba) * 8(different z corinates). And i wanted to display it.. somehow.. in a windows froms app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PointClouds come in many forms, with different sets of fields and different data layouts.

The additional metadata in the [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) message describe how many rows and columns there are, which fields are present in each pixel, and what order they're in.

**EDIT**

PCL has a [visualization library](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/overview/visualization.php). It should be possible to use it from .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203173/net-and-pcl-point-cloud-library . It will take a little massaging to convert a ROS message into a PCL message, but the formats are basically the same.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1